# MYSQL LIKE keyword error when selecting with patterns

Tags: mysql

I need to select all the urls with a string pattern (With out using RLIKE). String pattern is

url needs to be ending "%news.html" SO when i use the following query to select

```
SELECT *  FROM `search_news` WHERE `url` LIKE '%news.html'
```

this also gives following results which are incorrect

```
news01.html
news8098.html
```

Why does the LIKE keyword is behaving like this ? What is the best way to do this without using REGEX patterns ?

Comment: Try this:- select * from search_news where url like concat('%','news.html') limit 5;

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da7ca/1/0 gives the correct results

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are doing something wrong. Tried your scenario, Its working fine.

```
create table search_news (url varchar(30));

insert into search_news (url) values
('news8098.html'),
('news01.html'),
('news.html');

SELECT *  FROM `search_news` WHERE `url` LIKE '%news.html'
```

And the output is correct as expected

```
news.html
```